Need help proving that the function is decreasing.
I need help proving that this function is decreasing.
$f(x)=\sqrt{1-c^2\sin^2(x)}+\sqrt{1-c^2\sin^2\left(x+\cfrac{2\pi}{3}\right)}+\sqrt{1-c^2\sin^2\left(x-\cfrac{2\pi}{3}\right)}$ for $x\in[0,\cfrac{\pi}{6}]$ and $c\in[0,1]$
After differentiating once, I've gotten the result that the first and third part of the expressions have a negative derivative. However, the troublesome part is that the second part of the function has a positive derivative. Knowing this, I am currently stuck needing ideas on how to combine the 2nd and 3rd part of the expression some way trigonometrically to have a negative derivative. I have tried forming an upper bound for the combined expression (2nd and 3rd parts) but am unable to do so, obtaining a lower bound instead.
Basically, I want to show that (Main problem)
$sin(2x)(1-c^2sin^2(x))^{-\cfrac{1}{2}}+sin(2x+\cfrac{4\pi}{3})(1-c^2sin^2(x+\cfrac{2\pi}{3}))^{-\cfrac{1}{2}}+sin(2x-\cfrac{4\pi}{3})(1-c^2sin^2(x-\cfrac{2\pi}{3}))^{-\cfrac{1}{2}}\gt 0$
I have tried to use an inequality to form an upper bound, but failed.
$sin^2(x-\cfrac{2\pi}{3})\ge sin^2(x+\cfrac{2\pi}{3})$
$-c^2sin^2(x-\cfrac{2\pi}{3})\le -c^2sin^2(x+\cfrac{2\pi}{3})$
$\sqrt{1-c^2sin^2(x-\cfrac{2\pi}{3})}\le \sqrt{1-c^2sin^2(x+\cfrac{2\pi}{3})}$
$\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2sin^2(x-\cfrac{2\pi}{3})}}\ge \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2sin^2(x+\cfrac{2\pi}{3})}}$
Much appreciated for your time, help and ideas! Please forgive me for not typing out all the above steps I've mentioned.
Hello! I've used the t-formula to evaluate the expression to obtain the A,B and C as said by @River Li, now I get this very complicated expression after some factoring and have no idea what to do with it.

I've continued on and did this using the idea provided by Mr User
$sin(2x)(1-c^2sin^2(x))^{-\cfrac{1}{2}}+sin(2x+\cfrac{4\pi}{3})(1-c^2sin^2(x+\cfrac{2\pi}{3}))^{-\cfrac{1}{2}}+sin(2x-\cfrac{4\pi}{3})(1-c^2sin^2(x-\cfrac{2\pi}{3}))^{-\cfrac{1}{2}}\gt sin(2x)+sin(2x+\cfrac{4\pi}{3})(1-c^2sin^2(x+\cfrac{2\pi}{3}))^{-\cfrac{1}{2}}+sin(2x-\cfrac{4\pi}{3})$
$=-sin(2x+\cfrac{4\pi}{3})[-1+(1-c^2sin^2(x+\cfrac{2\pi}{3}))^{-\cfrac{1}{2}}]\ge sin(2x+\cfrac{2\pi}{3})$
The problem is that this lower bound is still negative. Still need help  with more ideas please!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

A solution based on my comment.
Let $f(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x) + f_3(x)$.
Let $p := \cos x, q := \sin x$. We have
\begin{align*}
  f_1'(x) &= - \frac{c^2\sin x \cos x }{2\sqrt{1-c^2\sin^2 x}}
 = - \frac{c^2 pq}{\sqrt{1-c^2q^2}}, \\
 f_2'(x) &= \frac{c^2 \cos(x + \pi/6) \sin (x + \pi/6)}{\sqrt{1 - c^2\cos^2(x+\pi/6)}}
 = \frac{c^2\left(\frac12 pq + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} p^2 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} q^2\right)}{\sqrt{1 - c^2\left(\frac34 p^2 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}pq + \frac14 q^2\right)}}, \\
  f_3'(x) &= - \frac{c^2 \sin (x + \pi/3)\cos (x + \pi/3)}{\sqrt{1 - c^2\sin^2(x + \pi/3)}}
 = - \frac{c^2\left(-\frac12 pq - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} q^2 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} p^2\right)}{\sqrt{1 - c^2 \left(\frac14 q^2 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} pq + \frac34 p^2\right)}}.
\end{align*}
Let $A := -f_1'(x), B := f_2'(x), C := -f_3'(x)$.
It is easy to prove that $A, C \ge 0$. We need to prove that
$f_1'(x) + f_2'(x) + f_3'(x) \le 0$,
or $A + C \ge B$, or $A^2 + C^2 + 2AC \ge B^2$,
or $4A^2C^2 \ge (B^2 - A^2 - C^2)^2$.
We have
$$4A^2C^2 - (B^2 - A^2 - C^2)^2
= $$
$$\frac{(1-c^2p^2 - c^2q^2)(3q^2-p^2)^2(3q^2-9p^2)^2p^2q^2c^{12}}{256(1-c^2q^2)^2\left(1 - c^2\left(\frac34 p^2 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}pq + \frac14 q^2\right)\right)^2\left(1 - c^2 \left(\frac14 q^2 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} pq + \frac34 p^2\right)\right)^2}.$$
We are done.

Thank you so much! Just wondering whether it is a typo for the angles as $\cfrac{\pi}{3}$ and $\cfrac{\pi}{6}$ and the $cos^2(x+\cfrac{\pi}{6})$ looks unfamiliar to me.

@KiaKeng It is equivalent to each other. You can verify them.

Oh wow they really are!

in the code you sent there was a -9 coefficient. Where has it gone? The readability of this is a bit hard. Or is it a different code?

@KiaKeng I adjusted it a little bit by hand. The result in my answer is the same as the result by sage. You can verify them by hand. By the way, the result by sage is the same as that by Maple.

Thank you so much @RiverLi.

@KiaKeng You are welcome.
